# OBS settings for recording presentation (still screen) with mouse cursor in low size and good quality?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, compression, video-encoding, obs-studio

How could I reproduce these settings with OBS Studio FFmpeg recorder?

```
Format : MPEG-4
Format profile : Base Media / Version 2
Codec ID : mp42 (isom/mp42)
Format : AVC
Format profile : High@L5.1
Format settings : CABAC / 11 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC : Yes
Format settings, Reference : 11 frames
Codec ID : avc1
Codec ID/Info : Advanced Video Coding
Duration : 2 h 3 min
Bit rate : 189 kb/s
Width : 2 560 pixels
Height : 1 440 pixels
Display aspect ratio : 16:9
Frame rate mode : Constant
Frame rate : 24.000 FPS
Color space : YUV
Chroma subsampling : 4:2:0
Bit depth : 8 bits
Scan type : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame) : 0.002
Stream size : 170 MiB (77%)
Codec configuration box : avcC
```

I have used FFmpeg's [mpdecimate](http://underpop.online.fr/f/ffmpeg/help/mpdecimate.htm.gz) afterwards and it does the job, but is there any way to do this already while recording?

Comment: Does your mediainfo output also include an entry under "Encoding settings"?